# Checked out files related to loaded solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am using VS2015 and I work with 4 different projects and sometimes 2 different branches for a project. In VS a Team Explorer, under Pending Changes I see all the files checked out, from all the projects ( they are all host on the same tfs server). Each time when I want the make a commit I need to check to have only the files from the current opened solution and not check in anything else.

I was wondering is there is a tool/extension/option to only view as pending changes the files that are included in the current solution (the one that is opened in VS). This way I do not have to worry that I when I do a commit I include files from a different project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map different workspaces and switch between them as appropriate.

Comment: This is a colleague suggested and I just tried it out and it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the solution/project/file in the VS solution explorer > Check In> then Just the files included in this solution/project/selected file in the **Included Changes** section, other files will be listed in **Excluded Changes**. So you can click Check In button directly.

Comment: This is what I used to do, until recently when I had 2 instances of VS opened with 2 different projects. So each VS had some check out files with changes in them (nothing marked as excluded yet). When I checked in the changes from one project, I did not use the refresh button and what happened was that files from both instances of VS were checked in.